# How to set argments after heredoc in Bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to modify the following script to

```
tmp=$(cat <<'EOT'
ssh user@sv7247.xserver.jp
EOT
)
expecto "${tmp}" "${PASSWORD}"
```

like following script because just I want to make short the script.

```
expecto "$(cat <<'EOT' "${PASSWORD}"
ssh user@sv7247.xserver.jp
EOT
)"
```

However the shorted script not work. It is seems to caused by the second argment `"${PASSWORD}"` is not recognized.

How is the corrent way to do that thing?

Comment: You are passing the password to `cat`, not `expecto`. While the *here document* doesn't not really begin until the next line, the command substitution itself continues until the closing `)`.

Comment: We're assuming that your real code is longer, since otherwise you'd just write `expecto "ssh user@sv7247.xserver.jp" "$PASSWORD"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would write:

```
expecto "$(cat <<'EOT'
ssh user@sv7247.xserver.jp
EOT
)" "${PASSWORD}"
```

Your readability is really suffering there. I would think twice about cramming that all together.